# Upload TXT file and display data in SAPUI5 responsive table

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a sap.m.Table in sapui5 in which the data’s in rows will be populated on uploading text file(.txt) which contains some details

*For e.g.*

***Test.txt***

```
1[tab]ABC Q

2[tab]PQR

3[tab]XYZ
```

In above text.txt,

1,2,3… are customer nos and ABC,PQR… are customer details. I wrote the logic for reading data from test.txt file on upload (refer below jsbin link example) and assigned data into  multidimensional array as shown in below image

http://jsbin.com/fenexuqule/edit?html,output

[multidimensional array value on inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PVFT.png)

When I upload the text file, I want to create a sap.m.table dynamically in which there will be 2 columns customer no and customer details and the data should be populated into their respective row.

Refer below table structure **(Expected Table)**

```
----------------------------------
| customer no | customer details |
----------------------------------
|         1   | ABC Q            |
|         2   | PQR              |
|         3   | XYZ              |
```

**Thanking you in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do...

**Convert your CSV to JSON and create a model object**

```
var aCSV = strCSV.split('\n'), row = {};

for (var i = 0; i < aCSV.length; ++i) {
     row = aCSV[i].split(';');
     aCSV[i] = { 
         "cusno": row[0], 
         "cusdetail" : row[1]
     }
}

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(aCSV);
```

**Create your Table**

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    columns: [
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Text({text: "Custom No"})
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Text({text: "Customer Details"})
        })
    ]
});

oTable.placeAt("content");
```

**Bind data to your table**

```
oTable.setModel(oModel);

oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: "/", //json is an array of rows
    factory: function(sId, oContext) { //this function is applied to each row
        var cusno = new sap.m.Text({text: oContext.getProperty("cusno")});
        var cusdet = new sap.m.Text({text: oContext.getProperty("cusdetail")});

        return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells:[cusno, cusdet]
        });
    }
});
```

Full example: http://jsbin.com/tobifiqoto/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It solved my problem, I want to give you Plus 10 votes but as i am new to stack overflow  and i have less reputation.

Comment: @Prashob since you are new I hope you don't just copy and paste my code, but also try to understand what I was doing there.